# Duplicate and Remove Table Rows through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have managed to make it so you are able to add and remove table rows by clicking an icon on each table row.

My problem is though, let's say you add two (2) rows and then remove one (1) Then change your mind and add one (1) row to the table again. Well instead of getting one (1) row you get two (2). For some reason jQuery is bringing back that first row you removed plus the new one you just requested.

I opened up Google Chrome Inspector and did see that if you remove the row, it does in fact disappear from markup but yet still comes back when you add a new one.

My table is laid out like so:

```
<table class="table taskTable" style="text-align:center;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Task Name</th>

        <th>Est. Task Completion</th>

        <th>Est. Task Hours</th>

        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control" name="task_name[]" type="text"
        value=""></td>

        <td><input class="form-control" name="task_done[]" type="text"
        value=""></td>

        <td><input class="form-control" name="task_hour[]" type="text"
        value=""></td>

        <td style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
            <a class="removeTaskRow fa fa-trash-o" href="#" style=
            "color: #d9534f; font-style: italic; margin-right: 10px" title=
            "Remove Task"></a> <a class="addTaskRow fa fa-plus" href="#"
            style="color: #5cb85c; font-style: italic" title=
            "New Task"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I then have the following Javascript for adding and removing the table rows.

```
$(".addTaskRow").click(function(){
    addTableRow($('.taskTable tbody'));
});

function addTaskRow(){
    addTableRow($('.taskTable tbody'));
}

function removeTaskRow(){ 
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); 
    par.remove(); 
};

function addTableRow(table){
    $(table).append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>"+
        "<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><a href='#' style='margin-right: 10px; color: #d9534f' class='removeTaskRow' title='Remove Task'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a><a href='#' style='color: #5cb85c;' class='addTaskRow' title='New Task'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a></td>"+
        "</tr>"
    );

    $(".addTaskRow").bind("click", addTaskRow);
    $(".removeTaskRow").bind("click", removeTaskRow);
}
```

Why would jQuery be bringing back the previously deleted rows when you add a new one?

I have created a JSFiddle for you to see exactly what I am talking about. Try creating some new rows, deleting some, and then adding some back. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sj7n1h1/

Comment: I don't see the link to the fiddle.

Comment: Just noticed it, and fixed it.

Comment: the problem is that you bind to all ".addTaskRow" in the document new event handler. you bind to every ".addTaskRow" every time it is clicked. for existing rows it means next click will create new row times rows added so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you are creating elements dynamiclly.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

Use

```
$('.taskTable tbody').on("click", ".addTaskRow", addTaskRow);
$('.taskTable tbody').on("click", ".removeTaskRow", removeTaskRow);
```

Also, Move these method outside `addTableRow` method

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lt7b97v/)

Comment: Rather than using                                                                                                      `$(".addTaskRow").bind("click", addTaskRow);
$(".removeTaskRow").bind("click", removeTaskRow);`?

Comment: Okay, I got it. I also needed to remove my on click function that I had previously inserted. It works now. Thank you very much! I will approve answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your elements are dynamically generated. and [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) docs say :

> Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery
>   object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind()
>   occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event
>   delegation in .on() or .delegate(). :

Here's what you need to do :http://jsfiddle.net/8sj7n1h1/2/

```
$(function(){

    $(".taskTable").on("click",".removeTaskRow", removeTaskRow);

    $(".taskTable").on("click",".addTaskRow", addTaskRow);
});
function addTaskRow() {
    addTableRow($('.taskTable tbody'));
}

function removeTaskRow() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    par.remove();
};

function addTableRow(table) {
    $(table).append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' /></td>" +
        "<td style='vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;'><a href='#' style='margin-right: 10px; color: #d9534f' class='removeTaskRow' title='Remove Task'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a><a href='#' style='color: #5cb85c;' class='addTaskRow' title='New Task'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i></a></td>" +
        "</tr>");
}
```

use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event on them so.

Comment: "*your elements are dynamically generated, you cant bind event directly to them"* - wrong.

Comment: oh sorry... i just realized my mistake :)